# How to add history widgets in SonarQube 6.2?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-web

I was used to manage a project's history on sonarqube 5.2 by using a dashboard like this under "Dashboards -> Timeline". I can't find a way to replicate this on SonarQube 6.2. What is the correct way of adding history widgets under sonar 6.2 ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dashboards and widgets have been dropped in 6.2. You simply won't be able to do that.

Comment: Thanks. Any chances of getting this back in the next versions? Or at least the historic timeline  ?

Comment: 6.3 (in RC now) reintroduces APIs to allow UI extension.

Comment: The timeline and the cyclic Java packages have been my most favorite used features in Sonar. Are there any chances we'll see them in a future version of sonarqube? And if there are there any plans when we'll see them?

Answer (score 0):

The widgets build-in SonarQube 6.2+ show a tend chart in the "background" behind the measures (see "Leak Period: since previous version"). This is not an equivalent replacement of timeline but at least something.
See screenshot here: https://www.sonarqube.org/index/clean-code.png